# Problem with understanding first (and second) derivative of a two-sided infinite series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, derivatives, special-functions

For the function $$f(x)=b^x-1 = x_1 \qquad g(x)=\log(1+x)/\log(b) $$ and its iterative notation $$ x_0=x \qquad x_h=f(x_{h-1})=g(x_{h+1}) \qquad x_{-1}=g(x_0) $$ with *b* from the interval $1 \lt b \lt e$ we can define alternating series with infinitely many terms with negative as well with positive indexes. Let us denote the idea
$$A(x) = \ldots + x_{-2} - x_{-1} + x - x_1 + x_2 - \ldots $$
and define it by
$$ \begin{eqnarray}A(x) &=& A_n(x) + A_p(x) - x \\
\text{ where } \qquad A_n &=& \sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k x_{-k} \\
\text{ and } \qquad A_p &=& \sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k x_{k} \\
 \end{eqnarray} $$
With, say, $b=1.3$ and $x=3$ the series $A_p$ is convergent and $A_n$ must be evaluated using Cesaro/Euler-summation. It is obvious that this is 2-periodic, that means $$A(x)=A(x_2)=A(x_4)=...=A(x_{-2})=... $$
such that it is irrelevant where I define the center $x$  as long as I choose the iterates in steps of *2*.

---

I expect, that this should be true for the derivatives in the same way, but with some examples I find, that this is not the case. 
$$ ... \ne A'(x_{-2}) \ne A'(x) \ne A'(x_2) \ne ... \\  ... \ne A''(x_{-2}) \ne A''(x) \ne A''(x_2) \ne ... $$
where I compute the derivatives in various ways, for instance simply by 
$$A'(x)=\lim_{h\to0} {A(x+h/2)-A(x-h/2) \over h} $$
**Q:** I think I must have some basic misunderstanding here (which, I think, is not specific to the given example function $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ here). Can someone explain this to me?

---

**[Added:]** It seems, I've found one hint myself: checking numerically I found that 
$$A(x_0)' = - x_1' \cdot A(x_1)' \quad \text{ where } \quad x_1' = \lim_{h\to0} {f(x_0+h/2)-f(x_0-h/2)\over h}$$
So at least the result is not completely random (and in particular not depending on problems with the Cesaro/Euler-summation), but my intuition is still unable to grasp this conceptually...

---

Numerical example using $ b=1.3 , x_0=3.2 $
$$ \small
\begin{array} {rclll}
   &   x_0 &         A(x_0) &         A'(x_0) &  A''(x_0) \\       
    & 3.20000000000 & -0.00119822450167& 0.0175377529574& 0.000817628416425 \\
   &   x_1 &         A(x_1) &         A'(x_1) &  A''(x_1) \\       
 &1.31536107268& 0.00119822450167& -0.0288702496568& 0.0102533145478 \\
   &   x_2 &         A(x_2) &         A'(x_2) &  A''(x_2) \\
     &0.412136407584& -0.00119822450167& 0.0779236358328&   -0.129878114856
\end{array} $$

Comment: Just to check, with Cesaro Summation, are you allowed to take derivatives?

Comment: @cal: hmm, good question. I didn't think about it; perhaps I can check this with another example-function, where the terms decrease to zero on both sides infinite indexes - however, at the moment I don't have an idea for such a function...

Comment: @calvinLin : It seems, that the Cesaro-summation does not disturb; it seems there is some systematic effect which I'm simply lacking to understand correctly; please see my added remark in the question

Comment: Before I try to understand this any deeper, are you familiar with [this?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series#Rearrangements) Conditionally convergent series sum ambiguously depending on their ordering, and a 2-sided series would seem to aggravate this.

Comment: @Zook: yes, I'm aware of that; but I think this does not apply here because we do not reorder. It's more that I think I have some "fiddling-error" while I'm trying to discuss the *formal derivative* of a function and then the derivative *at some x*. I think it must have something to do with this - but I'm not sure...